# Excel function to return a nested SEQUENCE within COMBIN()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence

My current function is:

```
=SUM(COMBIN(5,SEQUENCE($A$1,,$A$1,-1)) * COMBIN(4,SEQUENCE($A$1,,$A$1,-1)))
```

where $A$1 = any potential integer. So for example, if it were 3 it would return 120 i.e.

| COMBIN(5...) | COMBIN(4...) | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 4 | 40 |
| 10 | 6 | 60 |
| 5 | 4 | 20 |
|  |  | **120** |

I need to change the formula so the final number is based on a nested sequence of the input number from $A$1 so using the same example where $A$1 = 3 the result is 220 in effect summing the results of the formula with a decrementing $A$1 by 1 until it reaches 1 i.e.

| COMBIN(5...) | COMBIN(4...) | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 4 | 40 |
| 10 | 6 | 60 |
| 5 | 4 | 20 |
| 10 | 6 | 60 |
| 5 | 4 | 20 |
| 5 | 4 | 20 |
|  |  | **220** |

or effectively `=SUM(COMBIN(5,SEQUENCE($A$1,,$A$1,-1)) * COMBIN(4,SEQUENCE($A$1,,$A$1,-1)), COMBIN(5,SEQUENCE($A$1-1,,$A$1-1,-1)) * COMBIN(4,SEQUENCE($A$1-1,,$A$1-1,-1)), COMBIN(5,SEQUENCE($A$1-2,,$A$1-2,-1)) * COMBIN(4,SEQUENCE($A$1-2,,$A$1-2,-1)))`

but because I don't know what $A$1 is, I can't write it out this way as i won't know when $A$1-x will reach 1 and therefore stop summing.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to calculate a probability density function. Excel already has built-in functions for the most common ones. Is this what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a triangular matrix - I don't see any particular reason to count down from the starting value, you could just count up to it so the matrix would look like this:

```
1 -1 -1
1  2 -1
1  2  3
```

where the positions with -1 in aren't used.

In Excel 365 you can illustrate this with 2 steps:

```
=IF(SEQUENCE(1,A1)>SEQUENCE(A1,1),-1,SEQUENCE(1,A1))
```

to get the matrix in (say) C1 and

```
=SUM(IFERROR(COMBIN(4,C1#)*COMBIN(5,C1#),0))
```

to work through the combinations

[image]

Or use a Let formula like this to combine the two steps:

```
=LET(
rowSeq,SEQUENCE(A1),
colSeq,SEQUENCE(1,A1),
matrix,IF(colSeq>rowSeq,-1,colSeq),
SUM(IFERROR(COMBIN(4,matrix)*COMBIN(5,matrix),0)))
```

or shorter:

```
=LET(
rowSeq,SEQUENCE(A1),
colSeq,SEQUENCE(1,A1),
SUM(IF(colSeq>rowSeq,0,COMBIN(4,colSeq)*COMBIN(5,colSeq)))
)
```

---

*Lambda Version*

Define a Lambda function SumOfCombo:

```
=LAMBDA(N,IF(N<=0,0,SUM(COMBIN(4,SEQUENCE(N))*COMBIN(5,SEQUENCE(N)))+SumOfCombo(N-1)))
```

and call it with

```
=SumOfCombo(A1)
```