# Passing a SEQUENCE as an input to the rows parameter of SEQUENCE formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence

Possibly a solution linked to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67850640/excel-function-to-return-a-nested-sequence-within-combin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6bqe.png) but I am not sure. If you take the following formula as an example: `=LET(input1,2,SUM(SEQUENCE(3,,input1)))` = 9

[input1=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6bqe.png)

I want to change it so the input can be an array and applied accordingly what would be intuitively (but doesn't work): `=LET(input1,{2;7},SUM(SEQUENCE(3,,input1)))` = 33

[input1 = {2;7}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydPIt.png)

Is there a way to do this? N.B. "input1" could be any length or selection of numbers

Comment: I wonder is you could do this with a lambda function https://exceljet.net/formula/lambda-replace-characters-recursive ? (I haven't currently got access to Lambda because it is on insiders' programme so this is just a theory but could be worth getting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same sort of way, but you would run out of resources eventually using this method if the numbers got large:

```
=LET(criteria,{2;7},
N,MAX(criteria),
rowSeq,SEQUENCE(N),
matrix,SEQUENCE(N,3),
SUM((matrix-2*(rowSeq-1))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(rowSeq,criteria,0))))
```

You don't need to calculate the matrix as a separate step, but it looks like this:

[image]

so you can see that all rows apart from 2 & 7 have been set to zero.

Result: 33

---

*Lambda method*

I will hold my hand up and admit that I am inexperienced with use of Lambda functions. I think it's a bit tricky to iterate them with a list of numbers, but certainly it works if you set up a lambda function called SumOfSeq like this:

```
=LAMBDA(array,counter,IF(counter=0,0,SUM(SEQUENCE(3,,INDEX(array,counter)))+SumOfSeq(array,counter-1)))
```

assuming that counter is set initially to the number of values in the list which is passed into the array parameter.

This can be called like this:

```
=LET(array,{2,7},count,COUNT(array),SumOfSeq(array,count))
```

Result: 33.

---

*Note*

You could also observe with a bit of math that the answer is

```
=sum(<input>+1)*3
```

but I don't think that is the point of the question.

Comment: Thank you Tom, you have helped me once again. This does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome - it was an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below formula-

```
=LET(x,2,y,7,SUM(SEQUENCE(3,,x),SEQUENCE(3,,y)))
```

[image]